# how to get data from yml file using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to handle environmental variables using angularJS(v1.4)? Currently, am working with a web application which uses JAVA mainly and angular for frontend.
Here I didnt use gulp/grunt. The application can able to run using spring boot. We are handling different environment similar to other applications such as DEV, UAT and PROD.

We have bootstrap.yml file in which key&value pairs are there for defining values for different environments in server side and from Java files it is accessible.

My question is, Is it possible to get the values of bootstrap.yml using angularjs ? If not, how to set environment variables using angular without using any node package manager like gulp/grunt?

Comment: Add a REST service to your Spring backend that reads and parses the yaml, and sends what needs to be sent as a JSON response. Then use that REST service as any other REST service in the AngularJS application.

Comment: Yep, but, is it possible to get it without REST call?